# Using TFS, how do i see old version of files in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS 2010 and TFS. In the Solution Explorer the icon of files, changes to indicate if a file is checked out by someone else. This is really useful for team members, however if the file was checked out by someone else, changed and then checked back in, Solution Explorer does not indicate to me that my local copy is old and outdated.

I understand I can look at the "Latest" column in Source Control under Team Explorer, however these are extra steps and it would be nice to be able to see this right there in the Solution explorer, possibly with a different icon on the files that are old.

Is there an option or an extension available that would allow this function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VS does not poll in time intervalls for changes, you have to do it manually.

You can get a latest version of the file via the context menu and if changes are made you get a conflict dialog.

An other solution I dont really know.